# Can i call a function from inside mustache templates which takes parameters?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mustache

I have a function defined in `user_helper.js` which generally returns value.

When I call `getUserInfo()` (in `user_helper.js`) from *mustache* template,  it normally returns a String. But when I want results from mongoose query it returns NULL and not even shows any error.

> index.js

```
router.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  Profile.find()
    .then(profile => {
      res.render("index", {
        userID: req.session.userID,
        helper: require("../helpers/user_helper")
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("Unable to fatch");
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

> user_helpert.js

```
var users = {
  getUserInfo: function() {
    return function(userID, render) {
      var query = {_id:userID};
      User.findOne(query, function(error, user) {
      // Inside, return nothing
      if (error) {
      return error;
      } else {
        return user;
       }
     });
      return "Some Text"; //This one's return result
    };
  }
};
module.exports = users;
```

> mustache template

```
{{#helper.userInfo}}{{ userID }}{{/helper.userInfo}}
```

It should returns user information from database.
Can anyone knows about this or any better approach ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in your function.

The first one is that the `query` variable does not exist in the `getUserInfo` function. So the `User.findOne()` can't be executed.

The second error is that the `User.findOne()` method is asynchronous, so you won't be able to return a value as expected.

You should modify your */home* route in the `index.js` to retrieve the user:

```
router.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  User.findOneById(req.session.userID)
    .then(user => {
      res.render("index", {
        user: user
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("Unable to fetch");
    });
});
```

And in your template:

```
{{user.id}}
```

Comment: Ya i found that asynchronous method later. But can i write any global function where i can show my value ? such as, I want some value for my header.template and now i am writing that query for every single router.get(). do you have any solution that i write a single function and access from any router.get and send through res.render to my Header.template ?

Comment: You can create a middleware (with `app.use`) where you can attach your *global* variables to the req object and use them in the routes then. For example, in your middleware you set your variable `req.myvar = "my value";` and then in your routes you can access it through the req object: `req.myvar`.

Comment: router.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  var val = req.userInfo; // This one shows undefined. Why ?
  Profile.find()
    .then(profile => {
      res.render("index", {
        userInfo: req.userInfo // This one works
      });
      console.log(val);
    })
});

Comment: I can't answer without more info. You should check your middlewares.

Comment: If my answers helped you, you can valid and vote up my answer.